# How to make button content highlight animation?

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

I want to make animation to my button, which look like this ->

[image: this]

I want to change color of all arrows in sequence from left to right (delay in highlighting the arrows can be around 50ms) from white color to accent (border color).

```js
<button className="submit-button" onClick={showButtonAnimation}>
  <span className={'span-button'}>{'>'}</span>
  <span className={'span-button'}>{'>'}</span>
  <span className={'span-button'}>{'>'}</span>
  <span className={'span-button'}>{'>'}</span>
  <span className={'span-button'}>{'>'}</span>
</button>
```

This is my button element...

Do you have any ideas how `showButtonAnimation` can look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const[startAnim, setStartAnim] = useState(false);

<button className={startAnim ? "submit-button animate" : "submit-button"} onClick={() => setStartAnim(true)}>
  <span className={'span-button span1'}>{'>'}</span>
  <span className={'span-button span2'}>{'>'}</span>
  <span className={'span-button span3'}>{'>'}</span>
</button>
```

Then the CSS you can maybe have an idea here: https://codepen.io/TotallyCurious/pen/RJOawN

Comment: Thanks for link, it's exactly what I was looking for :)